# IllegalArgumentException: Path must be absolute when trying to read json in databricks

Tags: json, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

I have jsut started to use databricks, I'm using the community cloud and I'm trying to read json file.
I have tried to do this as following:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

df=spark.read.json('people')
```

But then I'm getting error:

> IllegalArgumentException: Path must be absolute: people

I have tried to acess the people.json file with different writing:

'people.json', '/people.json','Data/deafult/people' ect., the last one is based on where I understood that the data is stored:

[image]

However, that did not work and I kept geting the same error message.

HoWhenever I try to read it with sql.Context.sql it shows the table:

```
df=sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM people")
df.show()

>>>
+----+-------+
| age|   name|
+----+-------+
|null|Michael|
|  30|   Andy|
|  19| Justin|
+----+-------+
```

**So my question  is how can I open the json file with spark.read.json?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why do you want to use `spark.read.json`?
In you picture, "people" is clearly a table.

If you want to read a table in spark, you do : `spark.table("people")`.

You use `spark.read.json` when you want to read a json file. In that case you do : `spark.read.json("absolute/path/to/json/file")` but you need to know that path (and that's exactly the error you've got). I have no idea where your files are stored, that's entirely on you to know it. Where did you put them ?

Comment: hey, thank you for your answer. People is table. and I have uploaded it like shown in the picture. I have uploaded it to there using "create table"

Comment: @Reut OK, so, if it is just a table, no need to call on json reader ... just use `spark.read.table`.

Answer (score 0):

1. Navigate to "Data" -> "Create Table"
2. Drop the people.json file onto the "Files" pane ([Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gf24V.png))
3. Don't click on the button "Create Table with UI" but just copy the path that is automatically created below the file. E.g. "/FileStore/tables/people.json"
4. Now you can paste the correct path and use the read.json command. It will look something like this: df = spark.read.json('/FileStore/tables/people.json')

Answer (score 0):

You might need to try:

```
df=spark.read.json('default.people')
```

But as noted above - for a table it would be:

```
df=spark.table('default.people')
```